# Why does getting AWS credentials inside windows container/task via API time out?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, containers, credentials

According to the documentation you should be able to get the credentials of the role assigned to the taskdefinition from within the running task (container) using the following url: http://169.254.170.2'AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI' where AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI resolves to a part of the url.

In my case in a log file I can see it resolves to: 
http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/063b6cc6-0dc7-486e-ba0a-843a308b222d

But calling the API results in a time-out. What could be the reason the endpoint is not listening?

The container is running an ECS_OPTIMIZED image of windows-server-2019

```
private static async Task<string> GetCredentials(EnvironmentOptions opts)
{
    try
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), $"http://169.254.170.2{opts.CredentailsUrl}"))
                {
                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return $"{ex.Message} {ex.StackTrace}";
        }
    }
```

opts.CredentailsUrl = '/v2/credentials/063b6cc6-0dc7-486e-ba0a-843a308b222d' for example and is obtained from the environment variable AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

The error message I get is: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I really should get back a json class like:

```
{
    "AccessKeyId": "ACCESS_KEY_ID",
    "Expiration": "EXPIRATION_DATE",
    "RoleArn": "TASK_ROLE_ARN",
    "SecretAccessKey": "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
    "Token": "SECURITY_TOKEN_STRING"
}
```

At the Container Instance I run the following two commands from powershell:

```
Import-Module ECSTools
Initialize-ECSAgent -Cluster 'txp-dev-windows' -EnableTaskIAMRole -Version "latest"
```

And that resulted in  this where the last line actually never continued (= hangs)

```
019-06-07T10:15:06Z - [INFO]:Runtime is already installed.
2019-06-07T10:15:06Z - [INFO]:Docker version 18.09.4, build c3516c43ef
2019-06-07T10:15:06Z - [INFO]:Configuring ECS Host...
2019-06-07T10:15:06Z - [INFO]:Checking Hyper-V Network adapter
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:Default vEthernet adapter found for nat. Using this adapter.
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:VMNetwork adapter found with mac: 00-15-5D-2B-E1-89
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:Checking for network adatper with mac: 00-15-5D-2B-E1-89
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:Network adapter found.
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:Network adapter found with mac 00-15-5D-2B-E1-89 on interface 2
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:Getting subnet info from docker...
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:Docker subnet: 0.0.0.0/0
2019-06-07T10:15:08Z - [INFO]:Docker gateway:
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Docker Engine (docker)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Docker Engine (docker)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Docker Engine (docker)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Docker Engine (docker)' to stop...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Docker Engine (docker)' to stop...
2019-06-07T10:15:22Z - [INFO]:Docker subnet: 172.31.16.0/20
2019-06-07T10:15:22Z - [INFO]:Docker gateway: 172.31.16.1
2019-06-07T10:15:24Z - [INFO]:Getting net ip address
2019-06-07T10:15:25Z - [INFO]:IP address not found.
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PrefixLength                   32
IPAddress                      169.254.170.2
InterfaceIndex                 2



2019-06-07T10:15:25Z - [INFO]:Creating new virtual network adapter ip...
New-NetIPAddress : Element not found.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ECSTools\ECSTools.psm1:1370 char:28
+             $newIpOutput = New-NetIPAddress @IPAddrParams
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress) [New-NetIPAddress], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1168,New-NetIPAddress

2019-06-07T10:15:25Z - [INFO]:Virtual network adapter ip created:
2019-06-07T10:15:25Z - [INFO]:Waiting for it to become available on the device...
```

Then I found this in te AWS documentation: IAM Roles for Task Container Bootstrap Script 
**Before containers can access the credential proxy on the container instance to get credentials, the container must be bootstrapped with the required networking commands.**

So I added that bootstrap script to the container program when it starts:

```
                string script = @"
$gateway = (Get-NetRoute | Where { $_.DestinationPrefix -eq '0.0.0.0/0' } | Sort-Object RouteMetric | Select NextHop).NextHop
$ifIndex = (Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription 'Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet*' | Sort-Object | Select ifIndex).ifIndex
New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 169.254.170.2/32 -InterfaceIndex $ifIndex -NextHop $gateway
";
                using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(script);
                    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                }
```

But it did not make a difference.

Comment: What happens if you run in manually in your container, like docker exec and try to invoke-webrequest the credentials URL?

Comment: Also, check if there is a newer version of the ECS agent to run on the host instance as some have been buggy

Comment: @NHol Not sure how to do this invoke-webrequest. If I do it from PS on the instance like this 'invoke-webrequest http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/063b6cc6-0dc7-486e-ba0a-843a308b222d' I get this: Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: And according to the AWS website: "Agent updates do not apply to Windows container instances"

Comment: @Nhol. From the container instance I Listed the running containers. That showed me the url to use. So this is the command and the result: PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker exec 1b02ad086533 powershell -command Invoke-webrequest http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/e988d9b2-2e00-4235-add8-df6530b007a0
Invoke-webrequest : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-webrequest http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/e988d9b2-2e00-4 ...

Comment: I updated the post to include some extra info

Comment: It looks like the script to start the ECS Agent does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The exact reason for failing is unclear. It must have something to do that the EC2 instance is not correctly configured for the ECS Cluster. It was created manually and a powershell script of the initialization data connected it to the (Empty) Cluster. I had the to it that way because the Cluster creation wizards only allowed the use of Server 2016 AMI's. But to my surprise today it also allows the use of a Server 2019 AMI. Doing it with the wizard. The container code started to work.